# Bluetooth wont turn on after Update

Tags: bluetooth

I am new to ubuntu but I have been using it for about 6 months now and so far so good, I recently got an update and now my Bluetooth will no longer turn on. I have tried to toggle the switch under Bluetooth settings and it just hangs there in the on or off position but never turns on[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29w6t.png). I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: try to see what's in the logs: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

Comment: you can also see what's in the messages: `dmesg | grep Bluetooth`

Comment: [    3.730219] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.730229] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.730231] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.730232] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.730234] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.725011] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.725012] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.725016] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.907325] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[    5.907327] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout

Comment: What is the best way to add terminal snip-its like the one I did above?

Comment: now, try to shutdown and start the device again: `sudo hciconfig hci0 down` and `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`

Comment: Those two suggestions didn't seem to do it

Comment: try to find your bluetooth device: `hciconfig -a`

Comment: you can try to see the status of the service: `sudo service bluetooth status`

Comment: sorry, the command is: `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

Comment: It seems your version of snap-in is incompatible or the device version is incompatible with Ubuntu version, only looking at the logs for an answer, my bluetooth has a similar problem sometimes, (I didn't find the reason yet) if I put the hci0 to down and up again, everything starts to work.

Comment: After using rfkill unblock bluetooth and restarted it is now working

Comment: Thanks for the help